# Is Intrinsic Magnetic Moment related to length contractions?

Tags: electromagnetism, ferromagnetism

Hello Physics StackExchange,

I was starting to learn about magnets by watching these two videos by Veritasium and MinutePhysics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TKSfAkWWN0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM

I started with the Veritasium one, which explained how length contractions explain magnetism in a current. I then watched the MinutePhysics one, which mentioned Intrinsic Magnetic Moment. Is Intrinsic Magnetic Moment just a way of quantifying the magnetism of electrons due to their length contractions, or is it something else? If it is something else, do the principles of length contraction apply somewhere else in permanent magnets? Or is permanent magnetism simply inherently different from magnetism in a current?